# determine values given equation of line parallel to x axis and y-intercept.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the values of a and b for which the line $(a+2b-3)x+(2a-b+1)y+6a+9=0 $ is parallel to x axis and y-intercept is -3. Also write the equation of the line.

here is what i have tried.

$ eq : (a+2b-3)x+(2a-b+1)y+6a+9=0 $
Let the point be P = $ (0,-3) $
Since the line is parallel to x axis therefore
slope of line = slope of x-axis
$ -(a+2b-3)/ (2a-b+1)$ = $1/0$
$ 2a-b+1 =0 $

Now what ?

Comment: The slope of $x$-axis should be $0$, try to invert the equation.

Comment: $−(a+2b−3)/(2a−b+1) = 0$ ---> $-a-2b+3=0$ ? like this ?

Comment: No, what i meant was: slope of line $=(2a-b+1)/(a+2b-3) =0/1=$ slope of $x$-axis

Comment: wouldn't that give a same answer ?

Comment: You can't divide by zero.

Comment: ok then cross multiply and we get $2a-b+1 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Since the equation $(a+2b-3)x +(2a-b+1)y +(6a +9).1=0$ must represent the line $0.x +1.y=-3.1$, comparing the terms $x,y,1$ in the equations, you must have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a+2b-3 &= 0,\\
(2a-b+1)/(-6a-9) &= 1/(-3).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Solving this system of equation you obtain $a=41/33$ and $b=29/33$.

Comment: what did you do ? you put term of $x=0$? but where did the 3 come from ?